# Pycharm: Google-style imports?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working on a project that uses google-style imports. That is, use

```
import module.submodule as sub
sub.f(...)
```

instead of

```
from module.submodule import f
f(...)
```

I'm using Pycharm, which offers to import unimported classes and functions. However, it always uses the import style of the second example. Is there any way to customize it to use the first??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import

Set "Preferred import Style:" to `import <module>.<name>`

Note that [Google's Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) recommends using `from <module> import <name>`